# Insert digital signature in crystal report vb

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I referred this [link](https://topazsystems.com/software/download/CrystalReport.pdf) to implement digital signature in crystal report but it is outdated. Any updated solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify the use scenario. 
If you just need an image of a signature, you can simply drag a database column containing the image onto the report. 
If you need a true digital signature, there are 3rd-party solutions that automate the process of adding a digital signature form field to the PDF export from a Crystal report. The recipient of the emailed pdf can then digitally sign the pdf.